# linuxでプロセスをフォアグランドにもってくる方法について

Tags: linux

linuxでプロセスをフォアグランドにもってくる方法ってありますか？
サーバ上でバックグラウンド(nohup)でプログラムを実行させておいて，一旦ログアウトしてをsshで再ログインした後にフォアグランドで表示したいです。

Comment: ありがとうございました。screenやtmuxで解決しそうですね

Comment: 事前に`tmux`などで起動しておけば解決しますが、そうし忘れると非標準の`reptyr`などでシェルにつなぎ直す必要があると思います

Answer (score 2):

接続を切った後も処理を継続し、接続しなおした際に、プロセスをフォアグラウンド状態で実行する際に、よく使われるのは、コメントでも記述されている `tmux` や `screen` です。

tmux を使った方法を書いておきます。設定はデフォルトだとします。

```
$ tmux  # tmux 起動
$ some-long-command   # 何かしらの時間のかかるコマンド
...outputs...
```

このタイミングで、 <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`detach`<kbd>RET</kbd>を入力します。これで、 tmux のセッションからデタッチできます。

tmux に再度接続するには、`tmux attach` から実現できます。